# Sobre las versiones de PHP para Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache, xampp

Yo tengo la version de PHP 7.2.21, pero Laravel me pide la 7.2.5 pero sin embargo en la terminal me pide la 7.3.

Tengo laravel 7 instalado

**¿No pasa nada si utilizo versiones antiguas?**
Porque me deja crear un proyecto igualmente con comando de composer

**¿O debo de actualizar mi php de xampp?**

Comment: Y que versión de Laravel planeas usar?

Comment: La ultima que salió.

Comment: Agrega ese detalle a tu pregunta siendo específico poniendo la versión que usas

Comment: Como instalo versiones anteriores de Laravel？

Comment: Aclara entonces tu pregunta por favor, no se entiende lo que buscas

Comment: La doc https://laravel.com/docs/7.x#server-requirements indica que para Laravel 7 requieres una versión mayor o igual de PHP 7.2 5 ahora sí puedes usar una versión anterior a esa o no para tu Laravel pues depende que características usas, revisa el changelog

Answer (score 0):

Es muy importante que actualices a la **Versión Estable más reciente**, ya que no solo encontraras características nuevas y excelente compatibilidad con Laravel 7.*, sino que estarás protegido de vulnerabilidades que se fueron descubriendo y arreglando en las últimas versiones.

> Hay una característica nueva de PHP que me encanta:

Antes

```
isset($_GET['usuario']) ? $_GET['usuario'] : 'Anonimo';
```

Ahora:

```
$_GET['usuario'] ?? 'Anonimo';
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que tengas tu PHP actualizado para obtener las ultimas funcionalidades y mejores que el lenguaje te ofrece.

Pudes ir a esta pagina y buscar la ultima versión y actualizar:

[XAMPP Apache + MariaDB + PHP + Perl](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html)

Además podrás usar versiones anteriores si te han solicitado trabajar sobre una en especifico, eso lo haces especificando la versión  durante la creación del tu proyecto mediante composer:

```
composer create–project laravel/laravel nombreDelProyecto 5.4.*
```

otra forma de colocar la versión seria:

```
composer create–project laravel/laravel=5.4.* nombreDelProyecto
```

Answer (score 0):

Cada versión de Laravel indica la **versión mínima de PHP** que tiene que tener el sistema.

Si tienes **una versión de PHP anterior** y puedes realizar la instalación de Laravel esto **no es una garantía**. Tu aplicación probablemente tendrá errores de compatibilidad más adelante.

Tener una versión superior de PHP a la necesaria, **suele** ser lo adecuado (en casos excepcionales necesitarías la versión específica, te digo porque).

*A las dos semanas de salir Laravel 8 lo instale para probarlo. Yo tenía PHP 7.4.x, Larabel requería 7.3. Mi versión de PHP no era compatible (en ese momento). Había un error de sintaxis en una de las librerías de **illuminate** del core del framework... La version 7.3 de PHP, incorporaba la sintaxis de array `[1,2,3,]` (una coma después del último elemento) a los argumentos de una función. Esto ya no era posible con PHP 7.4. Yo busqué el fichero con el error, quite la coma y pude hacer mis pruebas. Abrí un **issue** en el repositiorio del framework que fue rechazado y cerrado, no fui el único que tuvo este problema: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/34435*

En general, hay que tener al menos la versión de PHP mínima que indica el framework y se recomienda tener la última versión de PHP instalada, si las anteriores tiene problemas de seguridad conocidos.

Si tienes que trabajar con una versión de PHP antigua, por compatibilidad con la versión actual de Laravel, tendrás que usar esa versión de PHP, si tienes que trabajar con esa versión de Laravel. Usa siempre versiones de laravel son soporte: https://laravel.com/docs/master/releases#support-policy